# ngFor in angular 5 like angularjs

Tags: angular

In angular 1 we can do that : `let tempClient in blabla = (filteredClients | groupBy: 'idRefClient' | values)`

How to do the exact same in the actual angular to use blabla in my component.ts

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve? Can you please share a more concrete example so that we could help?

Comment: for basic usage of *ngFor check this: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data